# Find The Count Of An Element Where Element Is Getting Identified By The Content Text Of Tag In The XML

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am trying Find The Position Or Count of a parent element ; when we can identify its child element with the help of it containing text; below is the xml:

```
<start>
<Item>
<ItemName>x</ItemName>
<ItemValue>x val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>y</ItemName>
<ItemValue>y val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>z</ItemName>
<ItemValue>z val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>y</ItemName>
<ItemValue>y val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>Head</ItemName>
<ItemValue>Head val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>Head1</ItemName>
<ItemValue>Head1 Val</ItemValue>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemName>Head2</ItemName>
<ItemValue>Head2 Val</ItemValue>
</Item>
</start>
```

Now as soon as I will find /start/Item[ItemName='Head'] this, I want to find out what is it's position or how many '/start/Item' precedes before this ItemName='Head' so that I can use that count/value/position and fetch further Heads Head1, Head2 etc... ;
ItemName Head will be static but Head1, Head2 will be dynamic.

I checked using below I am able to travers to ItemName Head

```
<xsl:if test="/start/Item[ItemName='Head'] "/>
```

So how I can achieve the goal after this ?

****Update****

I tried below code :

Just trying to print the count in the body but it is not working

```
<fo:block>
  <xsl:template match="start/Item[ItemName='Head']">
    Count <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Item)"/> 
  </xsl:template>
</fo:block>
```

Am I missing some thing here?
I am new to this so my apology If I am doing very basic mistake here

*****---------Update--------*****

Sorry for being inconvenient that I added the code in comment and updated the same in the question. So as it was suggested I tried that and yes it is working ; below is the working code:

```
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:variable name="var">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="start/Item[ItemName='Head']"/>
</xsl:variable>

 <fo:block  margin-top="9.50mm">
  <xsl:value-of 
  select="start/Item[number($var)+1]/ItemValue"/>
 </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="start/ItemItemName='Head']">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Item)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Do we have any other short approach for retrieving the index of the xml element ; just wanted to know am I writing unnecessary code for just to get the index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of e.g. `<xsl:template match="start/Item[ItemName = 'Head']">` you can select e.g. `count(preceding-sibling::Item)` to find out how many `Item` elements precede the currently matched `Item` as siblings.

Of course depending on your needs and/or context you might want e.g. `count(/start/Item[ItemName = 'Head']/preceding-sibling::Item)` or (XPath 2 and later) `/start/Item[ItemName = 'Head']/count(preceding-sibling::Item)`.

Comment: Just trying to print the count in the body   but it is not working                                                                         syntax                                                                                                                          <fo:block>
     <xsl:template match="start/Item[ItemName='Head']">
                Count <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Item)"/>
      </xsl:template>
 </fo:block>

Comment: @RitoSarkar, that code sample in your comment that you also added to your question doesn't make any sense, an `xsl:template` is a top level declaration in an `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element, you can't wrap it into  `fo:block` element (literal result element?). For your input sample, solely the template `<xsl:template match="start/Item[ItemName='Head']"> Count <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Item)"/> </xsl:template>` outputs e.g. `Count 4`.

Comment: @RitoSarkar, see the edit, of course there are tons of ways to write XPath expression using `count`, depending on your context or whether you know you want to select down from the document node you can of course solve that with pure XPath, without needing to add a template.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: That is working thanks for this, so what will be an ideal use case where we need to go for the apply-templates only?

Comment: I would say that your initial description of "Now as soon as I will find /start/Item[ItemName='Head'] this, I want to find out what is it's position or how many '/start/Item' precedes before this ItemName='Head'" sounds like you should have or could have that template match from which I based my original suggestion; as for use case, most serious/professional XSLT that does more than a single template with nested for-eachs will have different templates matching and handling the different elements and that way would have or could have such a template.

Comment: What is the fundamental difference between apply:templates and call:template ?

Comment: @RitoSarkar, don't expect people to use the comment section of a question or answer on StackOverflow to explain you or answer you further questions on the topic. If you have fundamental questions try a tutorial or book (or these days video course) on the topic.